# How can I use if the text does not equal to the text needed then error?

Tags: java

My code is like this:

```
System.out.println("do you live in Bahrain? (yes/no)");
GCCYESORNO = input.nextLine();
if (GCCYESORNO.equalsIgnoreCase("NO"))
{
    System.out.println("sorry we don't have your country information");
    throw new Error("sorry we don't have your country information");
}
else if (GCCYESORNO.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

I want to keep something in this code if the person typed any different answer than **yes** or **no** he/she will have an error.

Comment: Just add something along the lines of `else throw new IllegalArgumentException();`.

Comment: Read about java naming conventions. only CONSTANTS are all uppercase; normal variables go camelCase.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use and else condition as a catchall.

```
if (condition1) {
    block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}
```

[Here is a link to basic if/else and if/else if/else statements.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are just asking for a `if-else if-else` case:

```
if (GCCYESORNO.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
    // "NO"
} else if (GCCYESORNO.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
    // "YES"
} else {
    // Nor "YES" or "NO"
}
```

Then do whatever you want in each case (throwing exception?).

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Code ... else { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead a switch

```
switch (var.toLowerCase()) {
case "yes":

    break;
case "no":
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

in default case you have all other words.